# how to prevent custom navbar back button image to strech

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have set a custom image to my back button in navigationButton using the following code :

```
var backButtonImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "back")!
       // backButtonImage = backButtonImage.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0 ,bottom: 0, right: 0), resizingMode: UIImageResizingMode.RawValue )
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backButtonImage, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

The problem is that It stretches the nav bar button image like this :

[image]

How should I stop from auto stretching the image ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way on Objective C, first create a button separately and then add it to the bar button

```
UIImage *menuImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-main-normal.png"];
        UIButton *menu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        menu.bounds =CGRectMake( 0, 0, 30, 30 );
        [menu setImage:menuImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [menu addTarget:self action:@selector(backToHome) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIBarButtonItem *menuBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menu];

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuBtn;
```

You can do this on swift by this logic

Comment: Doesn't it ruin the functionality of back button that generated automatically from navigationControll ? Because I have set the custom image for my navigationController's back button.

Comment: @sali yes it will ruin, you have to call the back function by set a method on the custom button, when you add the customized back button you have to set a custom method too

Comment: @sali upvote the answer and also mark in correct if you feel if it helps you, Happy Coding :)

Comment: @sali, upvote the answer dude, if it helps you , this will help some people in future